# Solution for replacing string in all the scripts

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

My scenario is to replace the below string

```
/dboracle/orabase/product/10.2.0
```

to

```
/dboracle/orabase/product/11.2.0.2_org
```

Ksh contains following values,

```
export ORACLE_HOME="/dboracle/orabase/product/10.2.0"
export ORACLE_HOME="/dboracle/orabase/product/10.2.0_RDBMS" 
export JAVA_HOME=/dboracle/orabase/product/10.2.0/jdk/bin
```

I should change the **first line alone**. **I should not disturb second and third line**.

Using `find` , I will get the list of scripts and change it using `sed / awk` single liner command.

```
find / -type f -name "*.ksh" -exec grep -H "/dboracle/orabase/product/10.2.0" '{}' \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

Let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on my mobile device so don't have any way of testing it, but this should work -

`sed -i"bak" '/ORACLE_HOME/s/10\.2\.0"/11.2.0.2_org"/' file`

**Update:**

Ok, so as I had stated, the above one-liner should work. You can use it with your `find` statement as follows:

```
find /path/to/scripts -type f -name "*.ksh" -exec sed -i"bak" '/ORACLE_HOME/s/10\.2\.0"/11.2.0.2_org"/' {} \;
```

**Note:** `-i"bak"` is only needed if you want to backup your scripts before making the change. This will create two sets of files for all your scripts with original ones being modified and backed up with same name having `bak` at the end of it. If you don't want to backup then `-i` should be just fine.

Comment: How about this one with find and replace find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i /ORACLE_HOME/s/10\.2\.0"/11.2.0.2_org"/g'

Comment: I am not too fond of `xargs`. But that's just my preference. As long as your substitution works thats what matters. :) Also, I noticed `g` in the `sed` statement. That is for `global`. If you think you have more than one expressions on the same line that needs to be substituted then you need that. If you only have one / line then you don't need `g`.

Comment: If I want to change the second line also . how it will be?

Comment: For both lines this should do it - `sed '/ORACLE_HOME/s/10\.2\.0.*$/11.2.0.2_org"/'`

Comment: Or if you prefer `awk` then this should do the trick - `awk -F"/" '/ORACLE_HOME/{sub(/10.2.0.*$/,"11.2.0.2_org\""); print;next}1'`

Comment: I have doubt in the yesterday solution which u provided using awk for directory tree..

Comment: Sure what about it? Can you please post your question over there to avoid confusion?